# Does setting a virtual column as an index in MySQL improve query speed?

Tags: query-optimization, mysql-5.7

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

database version `MySQL 5.7.37`
server version `windows server 2016 datacenter`

I have two tables: [`rep_order`](https://www.ycxzhwx.top/yhr/rep_order.handle.sql), [`tb_user`](https://www.ycxzhwx.top/yhr/tb_user.handle.sql).

```
create table rep_order
(
    id            bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    code          varchar(32)                         null,
    equ_id        bigint(32)                          not null ,
    mileage       varchar(10)                         null,
    order_type    varchar(5)                          null ,
    report_name   varchar(10)                         null ,
    report_phone  varchar(15)                         null ,
    contact_name  varchar(10)                         null ,
    contact_phone varchar(15)                         null ,
    address       varchar(100)                        null ,
    lng           varchar(20)                         null ,
    lat           varchar(20)                         null ,
    order_level   int(1)                              null ,
    des           varchar(50)                         null ,
    user_ids      json                                null ,
    oper_date     timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
    v_user_ids    varchar(500) as (json_unquote(json_extract(`user_ids`, '$[*]')))
);

create index rep_order_equ_id_index
    on rep_order (equ_id);

create index v_user_ids
    on rep_order (v_user_ids);
```

```
create table tb_user
(
    user_id       bigint           not null
        primary key,
    openid        varchar(50)      null ,
    name          varchar(32)      null ,
    type          varchar(10)      null ,
    mobile        varchar(20)      null ,
    username      varchar(50)      null ,
    wage_id       bigint           null ,
    resign_date   date             null ,
    entry_date    date             null ,
    identity      varchar(25)      null ,
    create_time   datetime         null ,
    password      varchar(64)      null ,
    dept_id       bigint           null ,
    sex           enum ('男', '女')  null,
    client_leader int(1) default 0 not null,
    constraint tb_user_identity_uindex
        unique (identity),
    constraint tb_user_mobile_uindex
        unique (mobile),
    constraint tb_user_username_uindex
        unique (username)
)
    comment '用户' charset = utf8;

create index tb_user_name_mobile_index
    on tb_user (name, mobile);

create index tb_user_rep_wage_config_id_fk
    on tb_user (wage_id);

create index tb_user_sys_dept_dept_id_fk
    on tb_user (dept_id);

create index tb_user_type_index
    on tb_user (type);
```

A `user_ids` field is defined in `rep_order`, which is a json array type.

Then I created a virtual column **`v_user_ids`** for `user_ids` in `rep_order`, and set `v_user_ids` as an index column, the execution of the following statement is also very fast

```
select o.id, u.user_id
from rep_order o, tb_user u
where locate(concat(u.user_id), o.v_user_ids) > 0
```

Screenshot of explain execution result
[image]

But the execution of the following statement is very slow

```
select o.id, u.user_id
from rep_order o, tb_user u
where locate(concat(u.user_id), o.v_user_ids) > 0
group by o.id, u.user_id;
```

Screenshot of explain execution result
[image]

It seems that setting the virtual column as an index does not improve the execution speed of the query. Why is this? What can I do to improve the query speed?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Please provide a) the table create statements as part of your question (just the relevant columns and indexes), so not everyone that wants to help you has to download a file from somewhere but can see the relevant information directly in the question (additionally, you can provide a fiddle, e.g. [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/), with ready-to-execute code) and b) the execution plan for your queries (add "explain" infront of your queries). Also note that "select o.id, u.user_id ... group by o.id" is usually invalid, as MySQL doesn't know which user to display if there are several possibilities.

Comment: @Solarflare Okay, got it

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: @O.Jones Sorry, I don't quite understand. I have provided the table structure information and index information of `rep_order` and `tb_user`, what information do I need to provide?

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for your answer

Comment: EXPLAIN output from your queries will help. Also, if you showed us the actual definition 
 (the formula you used) of your virtual column I can't find it.

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for your anser. The meaning of the query is to view the user information participating in each order.

In MySql 5.7.37, json type columns cannot be added as indexes, so indexes can only be added through virtual columns. 

**v_user_ids** is the index column of `user_ids` in `rep_order`

Comment: @O.Jones
 I just fixed the problem description and removed some irrelevant information

Comment: Can you please quantify the "very fast" and "very slow" in milliseconds? Also, how did you measure them? Also please note that there is a difference between "execution time" and "time when i see the first row of the resultset" (which will be much slower for the 2nd query, so this might be what you actually experience/compare here). Also note that if you for example run your queries in the workbench that there might be an implicit "limit" used - in that case, make sure you disable it, because this will also slow down your 2nd query a lot more than your first.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries contain this

```
where locate(concat(u.user_id), o.v_user_ids) > 0
```

It isn't [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean). That means it can't use random access on the index you created on your virtual column. MySQL must scan the index: examine every entry in it to see if it contains the substring for the `user_id` you want.

RDBMS indexes work best when there's one value in each column. Your virtual column definition puts multiple values in that column.