# Slow queries contributing to high CPU consumption

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

These queries appear in our slow query log and we suspect these may be contributing to a high CPU consumption. Any insight on how to optimize them?

**Query 1**

Takes title of article and list of keywords and tries to match against similar entries

```
# Query_time: 2.103713  Lock_time: 0.045125 Rows_sent: 12  Rows_examined: 38450
SET timestamp=1645104904;
SELECT
  VID, title, duration, addtime, rate, ratedby, viewnumber, 
  type, thumb, thumbs,
  MATCH(title) AGAINST ("Title of article and list of keywords" 
                        IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM video
WHERE MATCH (keyword) AGAINST ("Title of article and list of  keywords" 
                               IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND active = "1"
  AND channel = "19"
  AND VID <> 40885
  AND VID > 12200
  AND rate >= 3.5
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 12;
```

Explain
[image]

**Query 2**

> ```
> # Query_time: 2.248775  Lock_time: 0.000104 Rows_sent: 21  Rows_examined: 241356
> SET timestamp=1645105175;
> SELECT s.UID, u.username FROM video_subscribe AS s, signup AS u WHERE s.SUID = 224378 AND s.UID = u.UID;
> ```

Explain

[image]

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ft%'

```
ft_boolean_syntax
+ -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len
84
ft_min_word_len
4
ft_query_expansion_limit
20
ft_stopword_file
(built-in)
```

Type MyISAM

48,312 rows in 'video'

241,350 rows in 'signup'

[image]

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we to see your table and index definitions, and your EXPLAIN output. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: You have posted the same info as the previous closed question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165126/how-to-optimize-slow-query

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71089039/does-setting-a-virtual-column-as-an-index-in-mysql-improve-query-speed) to check what information should you provide

Comment: I'm not sure from that screenshot of that tool that shows your columns, but it looks like you have no indexes. You need indexes. See https://use-the-index-luke.com for good introduction to indexes.

Comment: I added EXPLAIN. I think it's indexed isn't that a FULLTEXT query? Doesnt that require an index?

Comment: No screenshots where you can show text, please. Say `SHOW CREATE TABLE video;` and then cut and paste the output.  Same with EXPLAIN. You can indent text four spaces and get it to render as code or console output.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index on `(active, channel, rate, VID)`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE video ADD INDEX active_channel_VID_rate (active, channel, rate, VID);
```

It should be useful in satisfying this sequence of filter clauses.

```sql
  AND active = "1"
  AND channel = "19"
  AND VID <> 40885
  AND VID > 12200
  AND rate >= 3.5
```

If `rate` isn't very selective (that is, if a large number of rows have `rate > 3.5`) then switch the order of `rate` and `VID` in the index.

```sql
ALTER TABLE video ADD INDEX active_channel_rate (active, channel, VID, rate);
```

You could try both of these indexes and see which one works better.

And, if you have a single column index on `active`, drop it after you create one of the indexes I suggest.

For the second query, do

```sql
ALTER TABLE signup ADD INDEX (uid);
```

to avoid the full table scan of that table.

Oh, and switch to using InnoDB if you can.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try that but first need to backup the massive database.

Comment: Databases with less than a million rows are usually called "medium-sized." *Massive* would be several hundred million rows.

Comment: Well the ENTIRE database is large / border-line massive.

Comment: I tried to alter table to InnoDB but it resulted in 500 error for all pages. Any ideas?